# I’m trying to use getPart() to upload blob image into mysql in jsp dynamic web app

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlet-3.0

Part part =request.getPart();
I receive an error that can not find symbol getPart(String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will recieve an error as the method `getPart` requires a `String`

Comment: I have this in my code Part part = request.getPart(“photo”);

Comment: what version of javaee are you using?

Comment: can you post the the actual full error text?

Comment: The error cannot find symbol means the referenced variable cannot be find, most likely the package you imported does not exist

Comment: Found out I’m using Java EE 7 web

Comment: The problem is that NetBeans can’t recognise .getPart()

Comment: Yes, netbeans only recognize Maven or Gradle Projects